# Append several layers to a GeoJSON file with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, append

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(poly_lyr, f'{path}\\tryfile', 'utf-8', QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'GeoJSON', layerOptions=['COORDINATE_PRECISION=8'], onlySelected=True)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(line_lyr, f'{path}\\tryfile', 'utf-8', QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'GeoJSON', layerOptions=['COORDINATE_PRECISION=8'])
```

I am using these two lines respectively but it makes overwrite. I'd like to append the second layer too to the `tryfile.geojson` after the first one. Is that possible and what is the easiest way?

Comment: GeoJSON does not support several layers. You must write a separate GeoJSON file for each layer.

Comment: GeoJSON doesn't support multiple layers, but support different kinds of geometry. If all attributes are the same in both layers, a solution may exist.

Comment: Not sure about this. Because, we are able to do this in manual approach, as; right click a layer -> export -> choose a exist geojson -> save and click append layer in this dialog -> https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Capture2_35.png

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz and yes, in my case, I have two geometries for those two layers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to tell the code what to do when it encounters the same file. For this, you need to use for the second export:

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.AppendToLayerNoNewFields
```

```py
file_path = "path/to/file.geojson"

....

# Options for the second layer
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GeoJSON'
options.fileEncoding = 'utf-8'
options.layerOptions = ['COORDINATE_PRECISION=8']
# action on existing geojson
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.AppendToLayerNoNewFields

# Append the line layer
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(line_lyr, file_path, options)
```